# Increase the size of an element in steps by clicking buttons

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got a little circle in D3.js.

Now, I am able to create a button and it is possible to increase the size of the circle by clicking the button. The problem is, that I can only change one defined size that I wrote.

```
var button.on("click", function(d){ circle.style("r", 6); });
```

But my idea is to increase the size of the circle in little steps each time I click on the button. I was thinking about using a for-loop, but I am not sure if using loops is a good idea in D3.js.

Comment: why not keep a counter and increment that on each click and depend the radius on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for-loop is not the right solution for the job no matter if you used D3 or anything else. Probably the easiest way might be to just read the actual value when the button was clicked, increase it as desired and set the new value accordingly:

```
d3.select("button").on("click", function() { 
  circle.attr("r", +circle.attr("r") + 6);                  // unbounded
  //circle.attr("r", Math.min(+circle.attr("r") + 6, 20));  // capped to 20
});
```

The nested `circle.attr("r")` returns the value actually set for the circle (note, that this will yield a string, hence the `+` operator in front of it to convert it to a number). After adding `6` to this value, the new, bigger value is then set by the outer `circle.attr()`.

Have a look at this working example:

```js
var circle = d3.select("svg")
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 100)
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .attr("r", 6);

d3.select("button").on("click", function() { 
  circle.attr("r", +circle.attr("r") + 6);                  // unbounded
//  circle.attr("r", Math.min(+circle.attr("r") + 6, 20));  // capped to 20
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
<button>Expand circle</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there a chance to give it a maximum size? Using loops would be no problem, but without using loops, how can you say for example: If you reach size 20, you can continue click, but with no effect?

Comment: @DerickKolln Sure, you could use the standard `Math.min()` function for this. Have a look at my update, which shows an approach setting an upper limit to the value.

Comment: this is really incredible! thanks for that! I got a last question. How could i for example add a measurement tool for this example? Like, everytime the radius goes up/down, the measurement also goes up/down?

Comment: @Derick, chaining questions on the comments is something frowned upon here at S.O. Why don't you open a new post/question? It's free!

Comment: @Gerardo: Thanks for the hint! I can do that for sure